# Работа с geojson

Tags: javascript, geojson

Доброго времени суток.

Есть координаты типа:
    *Latitude: 55.633671

    Longitude: 37.769749*

Рисуется карта с точкой, но geojson использует другую систему координат

```
var geojsonObject = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [{
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [4172850.2481443416,7506727.67383059]
      }
    }]
}

//----------------- карта ----------------------
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});

var rasterLayer  = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.61, 55.75]),
      zoom: 2
    })
});
```

При попытке подставить свои координаты он ставит метку в [0, 0], как заставить его использовать мои координаты?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в одинарных кавычках.
Поставил двойные, все заработало с нормальными координатами.

Answer (score 2):

Система координат совпадает.
В [примере гугла](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple?hl=ru) данные рисуются по стандартным lat,lng. [Пример файла GeoJson](https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json) — относится к тому же примеру гугла.

Подключение GeoJson файла:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137}
  });

  // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
}
```

Пример JSON файла для рисования полилинии:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "letter": "G",
        "color": "blue",
        "rank": "7",
        "ascii": "71"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [123.61, -22.14], [122.38, -21.73], [121.06, -21.69], [119.66, -22.22], [119.00, -23.40],
            [118.65, -24.76], [118.43, -26.07], [118.78, -27.56], [119.22, -28.57], [120.23, -29.49],
            [121.77, -29.87], [123.57, -29.64], [124.45, -29.03], [124.71, -27.95], [124.80, -26.70],
            [124.80, -25.60], [123.61, -25.64], [122.56, -25.64], [121.72, -25.72], [121.81, -26.62],
            [121.86, -26.98], [122.60, -26.90], [123.57, -27.05], [123.57, -27.68], [123.35, -28.18],
            [122.51, -28.38], [121.77, -28.26], [121.02, -27.91], [120.49, -27.21], [120.14, -26.50],
            [120.10, -25.64], [120.27, -24.52], [120.67, -23.68], [121.72, -23.32], [122.43, -23.48],
            [123.04, -24.04], [124.54, -24.28], [124.58, -23.20], [123.61, -22.14]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

Координаты задаются в одинаковом формате.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/94383)

Comment: Добавил выдержки